# Is MongoDB good for searching email existence in a collection of over 12 million emails?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to evaluate whether to use mongoDB or MySQL memory engine for storing and retrieving emails. Basically I have an application where it has to decide whether to send email to the user or not based on the email presence in this table. It may contain over 12 million entries. Please suggest.

Comment: 12m documents ain't much, pretty much any db should be able to do that with the right setup.

Comment: @Sammaye it is 12 million at present. But its is can grow continuously growing over the time.

Comment: I mean having the index over email in MySQL will not affect inserts?

Comment: I would, in my opinion, wait until you get closer to maybe a couple of billion before you start worrying about this, just check the docs and that on best practices and it should be ok

Comment: Having any index in MongoDB or MySQL will effect inserts

Comment: I ran some benchmarks, inserts over mongoDB are pretty faster compared to MySQL with in the same environment. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Amareswar ACID? :D Basically, there are tradeoffs. Also, "fastest" isn't necessarily the only factor (it's not an Olympic Race) and "fast enough" is all that is required.

Comment: My data does not require any transactions. Data remains almost same with sparse inserts over time. I just want to use it as lookup

Comment: Then you have a scenario that fits MongoDB quite well in this case

Comment: @Sammaye Thanks. I too felt the same but want to get some expert insight.

Comment: You might need to be a bit more specific if you want some real insight, that's most likely the reason no has truly answered. It is a very broad and vague question atm, advice requires truly in-depth knowledge of how you intend to build this

Comment: @Sammaye Thanks for your time. I will be more specific from now on. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Just so you know, mailgun uses mongodb only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email store well suited to mongodb. Many people already doing this. Sammaye correct on 12 million documents being walk in park. 
General guidance on use cases 
[here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Use+Cases)

Bear in mind that there is a 16MB limit for each document - detailed
[here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/)

If bigger than that you need to use GridFS.